# How to calculate the duration(time) of an EDF file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, european-data-format

I have an EDF file who has 73 records and each record is 1 second.

[image: my edf viewer image]

I calculated the duration of that EDF file in 73 seconds,
but when I used a standard EDF viewer I saw that the duration of that EDF file is around 63 seconds.

[image: commercial edf viewer program image]

My way is wrong.
what is the correct way of calculating the duration(time) of an EDF file?

Info Recording:

Identification code: 0
Local subject identification: 111111-1111 X 30-DEC-1899 Sanna_Testi
Local recording identification: Startdate 21-NOV-2017 dcfgyfgj X X
Startdate of recording: 21.11.17
Starttime of recording: 13.45.29
Number of bytes in header record: 6,912
Version of data format: EDF+C 
Number of data records: 73 
Duration of a data record: 1 seconds 
Number of channels in data record: 25

The specification of an EDF can be found here:
https://www.edfplus.info/specs/edf.html

Comment: Identification code: 0
Local subject identification: 111111-1111 X 30-DEC-1899 Sanna_Testi
Local recording identification: Startdate 21-NOV-2017 dcfgyfgj X X
Startdate of recording: 21.11.17
Starttime of recording: 13.45.29
Number of bytes in header record: 6,912
Version of data format: EDF+C
Number of data records: 73
Duration of a data record: 1 seconds
Number of channels in data record: 25

Comment: inlined images and made them clickable, tweaked linebreaks and punctuation.